# ANT build script CSSlint output xml

Tags: html5boilerplate

Is that any way to export CSSlint output to a valid XML format with ant build script?

I modified project.properties file in: tool.csslint.opts = --format=lint-xml section, but I think this is not enough, because csslint needs to specify output file like so:

csslint --format=lint-xml test.css > results.xml

How can I modify ant target to work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basics: Ant already has an output property. So you can just add the format option and output it to a file specified as an output property on the apply element. in an h5bp project this will output "output.xml" to the root of your project.

```
<apply dir="${dir.source}/${dir.css}" 
     executable="java" parallel="true" 
     failonerror="true" output="output.xml">

    <fileset dir="./${dir.source}/">
            <include name="**/${dir.css}/*.css"/>
            <exclude name="**/*.min.css"/>
            <exclude name="**/${dir.publish}/"/>
        </fileset>
        <arg value="-jar" />
        <arg path="./${dir.build.tools}/${tool.rhino}" />
        <arg path="./${dir.build.tools}/${tool.csslint}" />
        <arg value="--format=lint-xml" />
        <srcfile/>           
</apply>
```

Comment: This works fine! The only problem is this target iterate on a fileset which mean the output.xml overwritten all time.

I need a solution for all linted css files show up in the same xml file.